# Is it essential to have same TwinCAT versions (XAE on Engineering PC) and (XAR on Runtime PC)?

Tags: twincat, twincat-ads, twincat-ads-.net

I have two PCs connected to each other in TwinCAT as shown in the picture.

[image: Successful Connection]

But, I am facing an error when I try to activate the configuration. Error is shown in the picture.
[image: Error picture]

There is a difference in the version of TwinCAT versions (XAE on Engineering PC) and (XAR on Runtime PC). As shown in the picture

[image: Versio Difference]

Is this error due to the version difference or any other thing and is it necessary to have the same TwinCAT versions on both PCs.

For further reference, The compile outputs are added below.

Code Generation Output:
[image: Code Generation Output Picture]

Code Publish Output
[image: Code Publish Output 1]
[image: Code Publish Output 2]
[image: Code Publish Output 3]

Code built Output
[image: Code Built Output]

For the TcCOM there was no subfolder in it. The Picture is added below.
[image: TcCOM window]

I hope this will help you understand the problem.

Comment: Minor note: You might want to remove the tag `twincat-ads-.net` as your question is not at all related to this library.

Answer (score 4):

The versions of engineering and runtime don't have to be exactly the same but still have to match the following rules:
Major-Release number have to match
Minor-Release number can differ. But engineering has to be equal or higher than Runtime
Examples:
XAR 4024.10 -- XAE 4024.20 -- OK
XAR 4024.20 -- XAE 4024.10 -- nOK
XAR 4022.xx -- XAE 4024.xx -- nOK
Regarding the last example. If you want to work with the current version of the engineering and still need to be compatible to older runtime systems, there is a so called "Remote Manager" for each major release which can be downloaded from the beckhoff website. Further information: https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_remote_manager/index.html?id=1584127271344589360

Regarding your error message: This is not a thing of versions. It comes from your c++ module instance. Please have a look in the compile output and the error log or even better, post it here.
Please check under System/TcComModules/ClassFactories if the related checkbox of the classfactory of your module is set.

Comment: I have added the pictures of the compiled output in the post. Kindly review it and let me know.